# Homeomorphisms between half open intervals

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Why is $[0,1)$ homeomorphic to $(0,1]$?

I can see why no pair of $(0,1)$, $[0,1)$ and $[0,1]$ would be homeomorphic to each other, but I'm not sure why it is the case that $[0,1)$ would be homeomorphic to $(0,1]$.

Can someone please help me understand this?

Answer (score 5):

The function $f(x)=1-x$ is a homeomorphism $[0,1)\to (0,1]$. Note that $f(f(x))=x$. $f$ is essentially just changing the direction of the real line.